# WinUI3 The project needs to be deployed before we can debug

Tags: visual-studio, winui-3

Im trying to build a WinUI3 project created with default templates.  I created a WINUI3 class library and connected it to a Blank App.  I am getting a dialog on build that says `The project needs to be deployed before we can debug.  Please enable Deploy in the Configuration Manager`.

But when I go to Configuration Manager, the Blank App's Build and Deploy checkboxes are already checked.  Deploy checkbox is disabled for the class library.

Comment: Did you check on multiple platforms?

Comment: @mm8 yes i did check

Comment: Well, your issue is not reproducible based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Solution Explorer, expand Blank App project / Dependencies / Projects, does it list the class library? If not, rt-click Add References, select the class library.
2. rt-click Blank App project / Build Dependencies - is the class library checked? If not, CHECK it. (Should happen automatically when you do #1 above.)
3. Blank App - is it set as Startup Project? (It isn't meaningful to deploy a Class Library, so the app has to be the startup.)